# php script to run at specific time

Tags: php

I wanted to run a php script every hour and needs to stop the script from night 8PM to morning 8AM.

Part of the code which I have created

```
$hour = date('G');
print $hour;
if ($hour >= 21 && $hour <=8)
{
die("Script is halted.\n");
}
```

cron job is set to run evey hour. But for some reason, it is running every hour not stopping from 8PM to 8AM.

Answer (score 4):

Seems silly to add conditional statements in your code, when you can simply just setup your cron to only run between 9AM to 7PM:

```
0 9-19 * * * php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/example.php
```

See [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_9-19_*_*_*) for explanation of this. On windows, you can simply set the hours to run in the scheduled task.

Comment: I agree, it seems better to let the scheduler handle the scheduling.

Comment: However, I suppose they could be running only part of their script conditionally (although it doesn't sound like that's the case).

Comment: IMO: Create 2 scripts then. Also, from the way the OP describes this, it appears like he's attempting to stop the entire script. This is a solid alternative though, and removes unnecessary conditionals.

Comment: Well, yes. I still stand by my original comment, regardless of any other speculation. I think this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if ($hour >= 21 && $hour <=8)
```

to:

```
if (($hour >= 21) or ($hour <=8))
```

or

```
if (($hour >= 21) || ($hour <=8))
```

`&&` == `and`

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$New_Time = time() + (6 * 60 * 60);
$Hour = date("G",$New_Time);
if((8>$Hour ||  9<$Hour) && (14>$Hour || 15<$Hour) && (20>$Hour || 21<$Hour)){
    echo "Your Codes Here
    Works nicely On PHP
    But change my timestamps.!";
}
```